# Batch Script to execute more than 30 oracle sql queries

Tags: oracle, batch-file

We have more than 30 Oracle query files which contain stored procedures and SQL queries.

I have tried to automate the process by creating a batch script which calls a text file "driverssql.txt" containing the file names.  Below is the batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 >output.txt
 ( for /f %%a in (driversql.txt) do (
    sqlplus uname/pwd@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXX) (PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXXXX)))"  "%%a"
 ))
```

The script above executes well but the issue is every time the script loops through, it creates a connection which is a waste and not the best way to handle this.

When I put the connection outside the loop, the connection is successful but after that the SQLPlus window is in a hung state and does not execute the queries.  Please suggest a better way to achieve this.

Comment: What code do you use when you put the connection outside the loop?

Comment: Ijust gave sqlplus @"%%a". I don't think that this is the right command to give

Comment: I believe you can't. Depending on the actual commands in your scripts, you might want to concatenate all the scripts in just one big file and then pass it to sqlplus

Comment: Show the `driversql.txt` in your question.

Comment: Its just a normal file with the contents as shown below

Comment: What do you think that I think is a "normal file" with **normal content**, please??

Comment: apologies i missed the content. the contents are the file names in a single column like a parameter file with                          a.sql                                                             b.sql                                                            @c.sql

Comment: are there spaces in the file names?

Comment: no there are no spaces. The files are mentioned in a single column.apologies that i could not put in column format above,though i tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "list="
FOR /f %%i IN (driversql.txt) DO (
  CALL SET list=%%list%% "%%i"
)

ECHO sqlplus uname/pwd@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXX) (PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXXXX)))"%list%
```

I believe what we'd need to know is how `SQLPLUS` operates.

What the above code does is accumulate all of the filenames into one list, space-separated and quoted. It might work - all depends on how you would cascade operations sql1.sql then sql2.sql ... using one `SQLPLUS` command

---

Well, How about being able to control which [set of] SQL files gets executed, and in what order?

**I'll assume that you can simply concatenate .SQL files into one** If this isn't the case, then stop reading now...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:tloop
SET tempfile=%RANDOM%
IF EXIST "%temp%\%tempfile%*" GOTO tloop 
COPY NUL "%temp%\%tempfile%.1" >nul
FOR /f %%s IN (sqlsched.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%i IN (%%s) DO (
  FINDSTR /i /b /e /c:"%%i" "%temp%\%tempfile%.1" >nul
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET "excludeme=") ELSE (SET excludeme=Y)
  IF /i "%%j"=="again" (SET "excludeme=")
  IF NOT DEFINED excludeme (>>"%temp%\%tempfile%.1" ECHO %%i)
 )
)

TYPE "%temp%\%tempfile%.1"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('type "%temp%\%tempfile%.1"') DO type %%i
)>humungous.sql

DEL "%temp%\%tempfile%.1"
```

Suppose we have a file SQLSCHED.TXT, contents

```
daily1.txt
special.txt
daily2.txt
weekly1.txt
```

and for example daily2.txt contains

```
D0S9.sql
D2S1.sql
D0S0.sql
D2S1.sql
D0S9.sql again
```

Then this batch will first read `sqlsched.txt` and then process each of the files `daily1.txt`,`special.txt`,`daily2.txt`,`weekly1.txt` in turn, producing a temporary file.

Reading the temporary file line-by-line will then generate `humungous.sql` containing all of the contents of each of the sql files mentioned. All you have to do then is run `sqlplus` using `humungous.sql`

I've included a couple of smarts - If you repeat one of the SQL filenames as `humungous.sql` is built, then that procedure is only included the once, so in the `daily2.txt` list, the second `D2S1.sql` would be skipped. However `D0S9.sql` would be run a second time because of the `again` flag.

This could be extended if needed - for instance, if you had the current dayname in a variable then you could add the line

```
  IF /i NOT "%%j"=="%dayname%" (SET "excludeme=Y")
```

and the line

```
dWdX.sql Wed
```

to ensure that `WdX.sql` eould only be run on Wednesdays

Comment: Thanks for the code. But its only executing the first sql file. The other files are not executed.